# url host mapping as config in swift

Tags: ios, swift, retrofit

We have many different apis with different host. I wonder that is there a easy(best) way do the url host mapping?

I can do a one to many mapping the host-urls with dictionary or guava like Multimap.

Such as below

```
["www.google.com":["/path1","/path2"]]
["www.bing.com":["/path1","/path2"]]
Net.get(/path1)
```

But the inverse progress can't gurantee the host's uniqueness

What i'm using now

```
struct GoogleUrls{
    static let URL1 = "/path1"
    static let URL2 = "/path2"
}

struct BingUrls{
    static let URL1 = "/path1"
    static let URL2 = "/path2"
}

class GoogleApi{
    let host = "www.google.com"
    func get(path:String){
//        Net.get(path,host)
    }
}

class BingApi{
    let host = "www.bing.com"
    func get(path:String){
//        Net.get(path,host)
    }
}

class Api1Google:GoogleApi{
    func callUrl1(){
        super.get(GoogleUrls.URL1)
    }
    func callUrl2(){
        super.get(GoogleUrls.URL2)
    }
}

class Api1Bing:BingApi{

    func callUrl1(){
        super.get(BingUrls.URL1)
    }
    func callUrl2(){
        super.get(BingUrls.URL2)
    }
}
```

I don't want to assign the host manually here , is there a more elegant way（use attribute?）?

Comment: So you want fetch the same path, but on different Domains ?

Comment: @bobby  That's  one of the requirement . I want call a  api just according  the path, the host can be set in a place  and the mapping host can be  found automatically

Answer (score 0):

I'd check out SwiftConfigManager, or CSConfigurationManager if you are using Objective-C. One of my team members just wrote up the swift solution recently, as we had different base URL across different configurations, and were able to create build schemes, employing the different environment configurations.

Over the last 5 years we used CSConfigurationManager on many projects with success, and much more than just urls, including app settings, colors, sorting filters, and even ui configuration flags, to enable/disable components across different build schemes.

https://github.com/marcammann/SwiftConfigManager

https://github.com/marcammann/CSConfigurationManager